# Maximum call stack size exceeded , on an scroll function

Tags: javascript

I am a complete beginner to java script and I can't understand on my own what is wrong with this function: ( I want to change the backround color when i scroll.

```
function whenScroll() {
  if (whenScroll() > 45) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#0f0f0f";
  }
}
```

Comment: because it keeps calling itself hence the stack size exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement (if) is calling the function again and that's what is causing the infinite recursion.

Here is an example for you to understand, it's a little different from your case but it's to illustrate.

```js
function whenScroll(e) { // e is the event generated when the element is scrolled (if the function is attached to a scroll event handler)
  let color = "white";
  if (e.target.scrollTop > 45) { // use the e.target.scrollTop property to get the distance vertical scrolling distance
    color = "red";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = color;
}

document.getElementById("test").onscroll = whenScroll; // assign the reference of the function to the onscroll event listener.
```

```html
<div id="test" style="width:300px;height:200px; border:1px solid black;overflow:auto;">
  Latius iam disseminata licentia onerosus bonis omnibus Caesar nullum post haec adhibens modum orientis latera cuncta vexabat nec honoratis parcens nec urbium primatibus nec plebeiis.

  Hanc regionem praestitutis celebritati diebus invadere parans dux ante edictus per solitudines Aboraeque amnis herbidas ripas, suorum indicio proditus, qui admissi flagitii metu exagitati ad praesidia descivere Romana. absque ullo egressus effectu deinde tabescebat immobilis.

  Post haec Gallus Hierapolim profecturus ut expeditioni specie tenus adesset, Antiochensi plebi suppliciter obsecranti ut inediae dispelleret metum, quae per multas difficilisque causas adfore iam sperabatur, non ut mos est principibus, quorum diffusa potestas localibus subinde medetur aerumnis, disponi quicquam statuit vel ex provinciis alimenta transferri conterminis, sed consularem Syriae Theophilum prope adstantem ultima metuenti multitudini dedit id adsidue replicando quod invito rectore nullus egere poterit victu.
</div>
```